# Installing Juggernaut on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, juggernaut

I'm developing a chatroom app in Rails and have read that Juggernaut is the best option. Has anyone seen a tutorial for getting it started on Windows? I can't seem to find any up-to-date tutorials online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Windows so I haven't tried to but take a look at https://github.com/dmajkic/redis for running Redis in Windows and [https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-%28Windows%29) for installing Node.js.

Those are Juggernaut's only real dependencies.